# File download progress bar in android

Tags: android

How to show the remaining KB's of file is to be downloaded in progress bar in android.
e.g 12kb/120kb is remaining..then 97kb/120kb...etc

Can we have this progress dialog as shown in the image[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UrlTestActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    URL url = new URL("http://nodeload.github.com/nexes/Android-File-Manager/zipball/master");
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                    File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder");
                    if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
                        testDirectory.mkdir();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory+ "/"+(i+100)+".zip");
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int progress = 0;
                    while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;
                        publishProgress(""+ progress_temp);
                        if (progress_temp % 10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp) {
                            progress = progress_temp;
                        }
                        fos.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way what you have described is to perform the download using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). In the onProgressUpdate method, you can update a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) to indicate the user the percentage of completion. It will look like that:

[image: ProgressDialog Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
progressDialog.setMax(fileLength/1000);

publishProgress(String.valueOf(total /1000));
```

The below code is only available after API 11

```
progressDialog. setProgressNumberFormat ("%1d kb of %2d kb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can use a progress dialog, as discussed in the docs. Alternatively (and perhaps more elegantly), you can use a progress indicator in your activity's title bar. In your activity, before calling `setContentView`, add this line:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

Then by calling [`setProgress(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgress%28int%29) you can indicate progress. When progress reaches 10000, the progress indicator in the title bar fades away. Note that if you determine progress in a non-UI thread, you should use a Handler to call `setProgress`.

Comment: How do i calculate remaining KB's of file..?

Comment: Usually the server response includes a content-length http header. If it doesn't, then you have no way of knowing the total size and you need to use an indeterminate progress (just a spinning wheel with no progress indicator). For that you would need to use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`

Comment: @Ted-Hopp Yes i have the  content-length http header..but what will i  be needing to show in the form as in image that i have atached **52kb of 118kb**

Comment: The way I do this is to set up a loop that reads only a small amount of the download at a time (say 4KB), update the download progress, and repeats until the download is complete (or until the user cancels the download). That way you know (within the resolution of the "small amount") how much has arrived.